# Debian 10 configuration as router for private to private network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, debian, dhcp

I'm currently struggling to get a debian 10 system working as a router between two private networks.

Allow me to try and depict the setup

Network `192.168.2.X` <-> Debian 10 Router <-> Network `192.168.1.X`

- Traffic on `192.168.1.X` comes via interface `wlan0`
- Traffic on `192.168.2.X` comes via interface `eth0`

"Debian 10 Router" AKA "Router" - not to be confused with "ISP Router" which is a device provided by my ISP, and routes traffic to the wider internet

**Devices connected on `192.168.1.X`**

- ISP Router: `192.168.1.254`
- Others: dynamic / reserved static assigned IPs

**Devices connected on `192.168.2.X`**

- Debian 10 Router is connected directly to a switch, which is then connected to...
- Another Debian 10 system running PiHole (DNS) with DHCP server enabled
- Other systems with dynamically assigned IPs

## Status

- The IP of the Router on the network side 192.168.1.X is being assigned statically by my ISP router (it obtains the expected address)
- The IP of the Router on the network side 192.168.2.X is being assigned statically by the PiHole system, and it obtains the expected address
- `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns `1` (Router) (this is set in `/etc/sysctl.conf`)
- Systems connected to the network 192.168.2.X are being assigned IPs correctly by PiHole

In relations to IP addresses, everything looks ok. However I cannot connect to the internet from a device on the `192.168.2.X` network. `traceroute` doesn't provide any useful information for diagnostics (just lots of stars "`*******`" printed).

I'm not sure exactly what steps to take next to continue diagnosing or fixing the problem.

I expect to add some more info as I try more things, however I will have to drop my internet connection to connect back to network `192.168.2.X` in order to continue investigating.

Here is the output of `ip route` (run on Router) - this is not something I am particularly familiar with, so I am unsure if this is what is expected.

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.2.1 metric 202 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.2 metric 303 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.2 metric 303 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.1 metric 202
```

The output of `ip route` (run on system connected on `192.168.2.X` network, NOT Router) is very weird

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp3s0f2 proto static metric 100 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0f2 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30 metric 600 
192.168.1.254 dev enp3s0f2 proto static scope link metric 100 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp3s0f2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.11 metric 100
```

Two of those entries are from the wifi connection, which should be turned off eventually

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 

192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30 metric 600
```

This leaves the following entries

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev enp3s0f2 proto static metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0f2 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.254 dev enp3s0f2 proto static scope link metric 100 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp3s0f2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.11 metric 100
```

I am unsure as to why there are 4 entries rather than 2, and why `169.254.0.0/16` is in there - I have no idea where this IP has come from.

## Purpose

The reason for building a network like this is so that I can set the DNS server of the Router for my own personal devices to point to the PiHole device. This is to isolate this DNS step from other users on the network. PiHole sometimes has unintended effects and breaks certain links, for example, adverts for products provided by google ad services.

## Diagnostics

From this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/118324/what-is-a-link-local-address) I discovered that link-local addresses are self-assigned IPs used for communication on a network where a DHCP server is not present to assign IPs.

This is relevant, due to the routing table which I discussed previously.

Changes made:

- Removed default route / router / gateway IP from ethernet configuration

Result:

- This enabled me to connect to the wider internet (via wifi) simultaneously while making changes to devices connected on my local ethernet network via a switch.

Here is a diagram of how everything is currently connected: (At this point I change the notation, will update the above diagram.)

```
[A] <- eth -> [switch] <- eth -> [Router] <- wifi -> [ISP Router]
 ^                     <- eth -> [DNS/DHCP Server]        ^
 +---- wifi (no route) -----------------------------------+
```

- `[A]` is the desktop computer I am using to administrate all the devices.
- `eth` on the left side is network `192.168.2.X`
- `wifi` on the right side is network `192.168.1.X`
- `wifi` on the left side is network `192.168.1.X` but there is no route

Here is the contents of the routing table: `ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp3s0f2 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30 metric 600 
192.168.2.0/24 dev enp3s0f2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.11 metric 100
```

Here is my routing table when the eth connection is unplugged:

```
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.30 metric 600
```

This indicates that two IP addresses are routable via the ethernet NIC. `169.254.0.0/16` [incorrect=192.168.0.0/16] and `192.168.2.0`. The latter is the IP of a device connected directly via the switch. [incorrect]The former is presumably any device with an address on the network `192.168.2.X`.[incorrect] The former is a self-assigned IP as no DHCP server was seen on this network.

If I try and connect to the eth with DHCP (all auto) settings, it fails to connect. [what about with auto except route?]

It is possible to ssh into `192.168.1.30`, this link goes via WiFi. This IP address can be seen because both devices are connected on the same SSID. (I think.) These IP addresses were assigned by my ISP router.

[A] <- wifi -> [B]

- A: `192.168.1.0/24`
- B: `192.168.1.30/24`

I can `ssh` to this device. [edit: no I can't due to password issue - however it may not actually be a password issue - I know what the password is it just isn't working]

Somewhat related to the above point.

So this is a useful thing to learn: Whenever there are IP address level problems, it is possible to `ssh` into a device using a link-local address, which is on the network `169.254.X.X/16`

Comment: Maybe post some information about firewall settings on the Debian system.  I think you need NAT if the 192.168.2.0 is going to the Internet.  Also your title says "Private to Private", but you're talking about private network 192.168.2.x reaching out to the public Internet.  Can "Other systems with dynamically assigned IPs" ping the ISP router's 192.168.1.x address?

Comment: @axus I don't know any details about the firewall settings on the Debian system. This could be something I've overlooked - where should I start with this? I assumed that my ISP router would be responsible for NAT? Is that an incorrect assumption? I do not think devices from the network `192.168.2.X` cannot ping the address `192.168.1.X`, but I will check again.

Comment: @axus I've checked again. No "other devices" can ping `192.168.1.254` from the network `192.168.2.X`. The DHCP/DNS server cannot either, however the Router **can**.

Comment: Since you can't control the routing at the ISP, you'll have to use NAT on any routers you control.  Yep, the ISP router is also doing NAT, so you will have "double NAT". The basic steps in https://gridscale.io/en/community/tutorials/debian-router-gateway/ talk about iptables for NAT, though I don't really know Debian to say if that is the modern way to do so.  NAT shouldn't be needed for ping to 192.168.1.254 though, add a static route on 192.168.1.254 for the 192.168.2.x subnet if you haven't.

Comment: @axus Looking at this guide - I did already read through it earlier today briefly... If I understand correctly, I would need another "server" to act as a hop between my ISP router and the Debian Router I already have setup? Is that correct or am I misinterpreting what it says? (Currently looking at the first part, "To start we need two servers running Debian 8 and the following")

Comment: please add a network diagram

Comment: @Albin !?! how ?

Comment: @user3728501 Start with the devices and how they are connected physically, then add at least layer 3 configuration (possibly other layers as well). Then you can add any server configuration etc. just google for "network diagram".

Comment: @Albin You're asking me to do this 4 years after the original question?

Comment: @user3728501 :'D I didn't notice the date, thought it was a new question

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have fixed the issue, here is what I did:

- in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
interface eth0
    static ip_address=192.168.2.254/24
```

(removed `routers`)

- in `/etc/network/interfaces`

set to default (file is blank except single line `source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d`

```
ip route
default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.150 metric 303 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.150 metric 303 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.2.254 metric 202
```

Currently not yet fully tested, still working on this, but `ip route` now shows what I would expect.

(Note that I changed some of the IP assignments)